# Running projects from NTFS partition on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ntfs

I'm dual booting Windows 7/Ubuntu 12.04. I want to run C++/Java projects from a NTFS partition, where I keep generally all my files and projects. I fiddled with the fstab. One time I removed 'noexec', the other I changed it to 'exec'. After that, each time I remounted the partition, it still didn't work using:

```
sudo mount -o remount,exec /media/mypartition
```

There was a somewhat similar question already, but it didn't have the proper answer for me or I didn't know how to make it work (note: I am a total newbie with Ubuntu and Linux in general).

Comment: I am late to the party, but figured I may have an idea to help you out.  You could symlink your executables to your /usr/bin directory and chmod them there.  That may get you want you want.  1) Symlink: ls -s /path/to/ntfs/folder/filetoexecte /usr/bin   2) Make executable in Linux chmod +x /usr/bin/filetoexecute  -- Assuming they are valid in Linux, that should work.

Answer (score 2):

NTFS does not support the file permission flags that Linux uses to check if a file is executable. In simple cases, you can bypass this by prefixing your command line with 'sh'. Like:

```
sh path/to/my/program
```

Otherwise, I'd recommend to recompile your projects on Linux, using the sources on NTFS. For C++, i.e. all native code, that will be necessary anyway.